# small python project - not sure if it's me or visual studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2015

I'm receiving an error in my code "name 'sales_total' is not defined" I'm working in python 3.6 in visual studio but not sure if it's me or visual studio. This is just my first type of project trying to get my feet wet in the basics but this is throwing me off. The code is below if anyone who has worked with visual studio could help.

```
def sixerstix(sell_price, sales_total):

    sell_price = eval(input("What is the average sale price per ticket: "))
    sales_total = sell_price * 43

print("The total made for the season is ", sales_total)

sixerstix()
```

Comment: Does your code have the proper spacing? Do you have indentation in your code?

Comment: I don't think I copied over the code right, this is my first stackoverflow question, it's edited now though. By the book I'm reading I believe the spaces are correct. If I indent the sales_total under sell_price I get a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is simply one of scope. The variable `sales_total` is defined inside the `sixerstix()` function; however you attempt to use the variable outside the function. A simple solution would be get rid of the function altogether, define the `sell price` and `sales_total` variables at the beginning of your code, and moving the body of the function outside.

```
sell_price = eval(input("What is the average sale price per ticket: "))
sales_total = sell_price * 43
print("The total made for the season is ", sales_total)
```

Now the variable `sales_total` is defined globally and you can use it in your `print()` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought you needed the def function at the top for the program to run. I guess I was overthinking it, and need to go back and re-read the first couple of chapters.